# how can I optimize array construction using Set

Tags: javascript

```js
const a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 0, 2]
const b1 = [1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
const c1 = a1.map(item => b1.includes(item))
console.log(c1)
```

how can I optimize array construction using Set,
I do this, but then I don't understand

```
const c1 = a1.map(item => new Set())
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `b1` to a set and use `Set#has`. This will improve the performance for large arrays.

```js
const a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 0, 2]
const b1 = new Set([1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9])
const c1 = a1.map(item => b1.has(item))
console.log(c1)
```

Comment: @pilchard Yes. I need an array of booleans